# Cannot get API specs with Flask Blueprints and Swagger UI

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restful

So, following the examples for swagger ui usage with flask blueprints (https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger/blob/master/examples/blueprints.py), I have the following code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
test_blueprint = Blueprint('tests', __name__)
test_api = swagger.docs(restful.Api(test_blueprint), apiVersion='0.1',
                        basePath='http://localhost:5000',
                        produces=["application/json", "text/html"],
                        api_spec_url='/api/spec')

# Operation TestOp defined here
test_api.add_resource(TestOp, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint, url_prefix='/test')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I try to access the api spec docs, the URL cannot be located.
I've tried...

```
localhost:5000/api/spec
localhost:5000/test_api/api/spec
localhost:5000/test_api
```

...all of which return a 404. I've also tried creating the app without blueprints, creating the docs with

```
swagger.docs(restful.Api(app)...)
```

instead. When there this is done and no blueprints are involved, I can reach the docs at

```
localhost:5000/api/spec
```

So, am I creating my application incorrectly with blueprints, or am I just not hitting the right URL to get access to the docs?

Comment: Did you try `localhost:5000/tests/api/spec`?

Comment: Just did - still a 404. :/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're just not hitting the right URL.  Because your blueprint url_prefix is "/test", the Swagger spec url should be at:

```
localhost:5000/test/api/spec
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but I ran into this exact problem today, trying to use flask-restful-swagger with my (somewhat) modern flask + python3 app that uses blueprints.  Same problem, no errors, just no spec available no matter what i tried.

I finally abandoned this package (as it seems like it hasn't been very active anyway), even though I like the markup better with this package.

I chose Flasgger, which seemed to be updated more recently.  In 10 minutes I had it up and running.  Code and short tutorial are here: https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger

Comment: Virtually effortless + minimal code changes if already using Flask

Answer (score -1):

something wrong in swagger.docs()

```
from flask_restful import Api
test_blueprint = Blueprint('tests', __name__)
test_api = swagger.docs(Api(test_blueprint)...)
app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint)
```

what'more

```
main_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/demo')
```